# Blazor, Accept-Language Header

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0

Started localization in an app with german as default and english as additional:

```
string[] supportedCultures = new string[] { "de-DE", "en-US" };
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

with e.g. `Index.resx` & `Index.en-US.resx`

So it only shows the english resources if the browser is set to "English (United States)" obviously, but it should also show english for other cultures.

So the resx been renamed to `Index.resx` & `Index.en.resx`, and the code changed to

```
string[] supportedCultures = new string[] { "de-DE", "en" };
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

which works as intended, every english culture get english resources.

Next logical step, change `de-DE` to `de` just for uniform:

```
string[] supportedCultures = new string[] { "de", "en" };
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

and it totally breaks. No english resources gets displayed whatsoever. Setting a breakpoint reveales that the string just get parsed fine and the cultures are all set as expected, though no english resources get displayed.

I know i can just go with the second option and everything works, but i'd just really would like to understand whats going on here, is this a bug or am i just understanding this totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused that you did not run into this with your first variant too. But without testing it I see that you set your default culture to supportedCultures[0] aka de-DE or de depending on your example so every language set in the browser except english should display the german resources or more general the resources stored in the default resourcefile.